# Getting the ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,600' error when setting regression fit

Tags: machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owdst.png)

Getting the ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,600' error when setting regression fit

Comment: You need to replace your commas with dots. Next time, consider parsing your code instead of an image of it ;)

Comment: Can u pls. be specific..Thnx..I am passing two values to my regression fit, One is Area value and the other one is the price....

Comment: Use `float(your_string.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: @SekaranRamalingam please edit your question to include your code as text.

Comment: Maybe thinking in terms of local currency instead of decimal?

Answer (score 1):

as @Thomas Schillaci suggest you need to do something like this:

```
new_df["Area"]  = new_df["Area"].str.replace(",", ".")
```

after that, you can cast your values to float without problems.

using the str in pandas is much faster than applying the function by other means.